# Constrict generic class in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have an operator class that has some classes and methods in it that deals with mathematical operations. The operator class is generic and extends Number so my operations can be with ints, doubles, floats, etc.

```
public class OperatorClass<T extends Number>
```

In this class there is an abstract class that provides a method in which numbers are operated upon using the calculate method

```
abstract class Op<T extends Number> {
    abstract T calculate(DataSet<? extends Number> ds);
}
```

There are multiple classes that extend Op like the AddOp for example:

```
class AddOp<T extends Number> extends Op<T>{
    public T calculate(DataSet<? extends Number> ds) {
        return ds.getLeft() +  ds.getRight();
    }
}
```

And my DataSet is just a data class that looks like this:

```
public class DataSet<T extends Number> {
private T left;
private T right;

public DataSet(T left, T right) {
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
}

public T getLeft() {
    return left;
}
public T getRight() {
    return right;
}
```

}

The problem I am having is that the line `ds.getLeft() +  ds.getRight()` is not compiling because the Number abstract class cannot do a + operator. How do i get my DataSet to be a type of Number (like a wildcard class) so i can do math operations on it.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

**Edit**

So a workaround to the problem is that I used some if statements and then got the correct primitive datatype like so

```
Number result = null;
if(ds.getLeft().getClass().equals(Integer.class))
     result = new Integer(ds.getLeft().intValue() + ds.getRight().intValue());
....
return (T) result;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decide at what resolution you are going to add.  In other words, are you calling `left.getInteger()` or `left.getFloat()`?

There are a number of ways of solving this, but it really boils down to what you intend to do.  If you want your numbers to truly remain objects, you cannot use the `+` plus operator because that doesn't work on objects.  You need a `left.plus(right)` style method call which returns a new number.

If you don't care about maintaining your numbers as objects during math exercises (perhaps they were just objects for the sake of collection storage or something) then you replace the `public T getLeft()` with `public long getLeft()` and rely on the internal number's `left.getLongValue()` to do the conversion.  Or you just expose the two `Number` objects and allow the "external" user to do the appropriate `getXxxValue()` calls.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but I'm trying to making it so I can have an OperatorClass<Integer> and all the operations would be on integers and later on I could make an OperatorClass<Double> object and all the operations would now be on doubles.

Comment: It is possible, but if you want your numbers to be objects, you need to implement methods for the arithmetic operations.  Built in mathematical operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, etc. only function on built-in types, they don't function on `Objects` with the solitary exception that `+` works to concatenate `Strings`.

Comment: I just used some if statements to check if the number was an int, double, float, etc then got the int value, double value, etc from the number and did the arithmetic operation

Answer (score 0):

Numeric types are primitive types, you can't implement arithmetic operations over them generically. Java's generics don't work like C++ templates and don't generate type-specific code, and there is no way to add two Number instances or instances of any other of the primitive wrapper types.

What you're trying to do is impossible in Java, and you'll have to write separate methods for `int`, `doubles`, etc. (Or whichever you want to support.)

Answer (score 0):

Can't overload the operators in Java. So simplest is to change:

```
    return ds.getLeft() +  ds.getRight();
```

to (something like)

```
    return ds.getLeft().getDouble() +  ds.getRight().getDouble();
```

I say *something like* because you might have to deal with a bit type casting.

Thought there are other methods `getFloat() getInt()...` I picked double as there won't be any loss by truncation.